# Google Search Console API

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

I need help building a basic query in PHP for the Search Console API. I just want to pull clicks and impression data for a client. I can't find any examples in PHP. I can work with Google Analytics API just fine, but can't figure out how to connect to Search Console. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the [readme](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) for the php client. Look at the [quick start for Python](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/quickstart/quickstart-python) if you need basic idea of how the flow works.

When you get stuck google around and then post here again.

Good luck.